# The logic and Code sample for conversion of Osm:Relation to GeoJson

Tags: java, python, geometry, openstreetmap, geojson

I just want to convert `osm` data to `geojson` where it is pretty simple with node and way tags of `osm` data, but relation which is giving complex can't find the logic to convert `osm` relation to `geojson` format especially how to form coordinates parameter of `geojson` based on their roles (ex. `Inner`, `outer`, `admin_centre`, `riverbank`, `side_stream`, `main_stream`, `from`, `via`, `to`, `forward`, `backward`, `stop_entry_only`, `stop_exit_only`, and `platform_exit_only`).

As simple, how to form relation member's latitude and longitude in coordinates parameter of `geojson`.

I have tried many documentation but no logics or code found in java and python.

In python: https://pypi.org/project/osm2geojson/
OSM Official: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org
geojson Official: https://geojson.org/
Sample data: https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/maldives-latest.osm.bz2
https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/bhutan-latest.osm.pbf

But no luck

I have tried in java and python but reason is I could not find the logic behind the conversion of the relation tags from osm to geojson

I am expecting the logic behind the conversion of the relation tags from `osm` to `geojson` and sample code for that.

Comment: Maybe this Overpass turbo example helps: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Jcl. Click run, then export, save as GeoJSON. Take a look at the result. You can change the original query to see how other OSM relations are exported to GeoJSON. Note that there is not just one "correct" way for converting OSM data to GeoJSON.

Comment: thanks for the response. but i need a logic of geojson structure formation of geojson or code snippet. but   overpass-turbo.eu/s/Jcl is simple osm query tool....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "logic of geojson structure formation of geojson" is supposed to mean. Take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GeoJSON which lists various tools for converting OSM data to GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

The [GeoJSON](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GeoJSON) page in the OSM Wiki lists various tools for converting OSM data to GeoJSON:

> - [ogr2ogr](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ogr2ogr) – General tool for conversion between many geo data formats including GeoJSON and OSM XML
> - [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson#readme) - Specialized tool to convert OSM data to GeoJSON
> - [minjur](https://github.com/mapbox/minjur) – Osmium-based converter of OSM data to (line delimited) GeoJSON
> - [JOSM/Plugins/GeoJSON](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/GeoJSON) – ''should'' allow you to open a GeoJSON file with JOSM (''does it work?'')
> - Help question: [Software/Libraries to Convert OSM Data to GeoJSON (without using API)](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/18255/softwarelibraries-to-convert-osm-data-to-geojson-without-using-api)
> - [BBBike.org extract service](https://extract.bbbike.org/?format=geojson.xz) offers GeoJSON for an area of your choosing, updated weekly

The above mentioned osmtogeojson is used by overpass-turbo for creating GeoJSON exports.